# In Python I need to search a number in a text file and take the next word avec the comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a text file with a  list of number and names separeted by commas.

Text file (The numbers are not sorted in the file) :

```
1,name.to.ping,hello,blah-blah
44,Value-to-check,good,foo
2,other-name,foo,blue
3, etc...
```

I need to write a Python3 software that open the text file, search for the number and print only the first text after the ,

If I search 2 I need it to print "other-name"

Answer (score 0):

You could use `csv` module to load the data ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html)). Assuming the numbers in first row are unique:

```
import csv

def load_data(filename='file.csv'):
    with open(filename, newline='') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        return {int(row[0]): row[1] for row in csvreader}

data = load_data()
print(data[2])
```

Prints:

```
other-name
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex.

> ```
> import re
> number = 1
> filename = "test.txt"
> fileContent = "".join(open(filename , "r").readlines())
> print(re.search(f"(?<=^{str(number)},)[a-zA-Z0-9]+", fileContent)[0])
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**For python3:**

```
import csv
import codecs
number = input('Enter number to find\n')
ifile  = open('file.csv', "rb")
read = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(ifile, 'utf-8'))
for row in read :

    #print (row[1])
    if number == row[0] :
        print(row[1])
```

**For python2**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import sys

#input number you want to search
number = raw_input('Enter number to find\n')

csv_file = csv.reader(open('file.txt', "rb"), delimiter=",")


#loop through csv list
for row in csv_file:
    #if current rows 1nd value is equal to input, print that row
    if number == row[0]:
         print row[1]
```

Output:

```
Enter number to find
2
other-name
```

Comment: Question asked for Python3

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working exemple :

```
with open('/tmp/1.txt','r') as fp:
   lines = fp.read().splitlines()
   for line in lines:
       line = line.strip()
       items = line.split(",")
       ist_col = items[0]
       sec_col = items[1]
       if ist_col=="<pat>":
          print(sec_col)
```

[check out my code here](https://www.usessionbuddy.com/user/abhiphull/session.root.27303.071620190859.html/)